# AudioOutputUnitStart fail with return code 561145187

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, avaudiosession, audiounit

Our app AudioOutputUnitStart always return the invoke AVAudioSessionErrorCodeCannotStartRecording, we invoke this method is in the foreground is not in the background, when appear the problem, the background no app running, What is the reason and how to debug it.Thanks!

```
    OSStatus status = AudioOutputUnitStart(recordUnit);
    if (status!=noErr) {
       status = 561145187
    }
```

Comment: I met the same question in iPad. Our Codes work well in iPhone. I have no idea what's happening. It seems like a system bug.

Comment: same here. seems not a hot question, maybe we all have stepped on some obvious bug?

Comment: There are no problems when we use our app on the iPad. We can't stepped on it and this made our users feel bad. Do you know how to reproduce it?

Comment: It appears on iPad Pro, e.g. "iPad 8,9", and the latest "iPad 13,x"

Comment: This problem is a bug in Apple's system, users remove the protective shell can be used normally.

Comment: you kidding right? remove the physical protective shell?

Comment: After restarting the iOS system, is the problem there ?